# Weechat get config variable

Tags: irc, weechat

How can I get a Weechat config variable? For instance, I can set configs:

```
/set irc.servers.freenode.ssl on
```

How can I retrieve the values I set?

Answer (score 7):

To check the value of a config variable, you can just do this:

```
/set irc.servers.freenode.ssl
```

From the docs:

> [core]  /set  [<option> [<value>]]

The value is optional and when not present, it returns the value of the variable.  Intuitively, it might seem like leaving off the value would unset the variable or set it to the empty string, but you would need to use the `/unset` command instead.

Also note, you can use wildcards to view multiple config variables at once:

```
/set irc.servers.freenode.*
```

Comment: Why is there no `/get`? ..